# paypalrestsdk with Django integration issue

Tags: python, json, django, paypal

I am trying to setup Paypal express checkout with REST API but when I click checkout with Paypal I get modal window and it just spins forever.

Payment create view:

```
def payment_create(request):
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

paypalrestsdk.configure({
'mode': settings.PAYPAL_MODE,
'client_id': settings.PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID,
'client_secret': settings.PAYPAL_CLIENT_SECRET
})

# Create payment object
payment = paypalrestsdk.Payment({
  "intent": "sale",

  # Set payment method
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal"},

  # Set redirect urls
  "redirect_urls": {
    "return_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/payment_done/",
    "cancel_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/payment_error/"},

  # Set transaction object
  "transactions": [{
    "amount": {
      "total": "10.00",
      "currency": "USD"},
    "description": "payment description"}]})

# Create Payment and return status
if payment.create():
    print("Payment[%s] created successfully" % (payment.id))
    request.session["paymentID"] = payment.id
    # Redirect the user to given approval url
    for link in payment.links:
        if link.method == "REDIRECT":
            print("Redirect for approval: %s" % (link.href))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(link.href)
else:
    print("Error while creating payment:")
    print(payment.error)
```

Cart.html template:

```
<div id="paypal-button"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" data-version-4></script>
<script>
    paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'sandbox', // Optional: specify 'sandbox' environment

        payment: function(resolve, reject) {

            var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/payment_create/';

            paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL)
                .then(function(data) { resolve(data.paymentID);  })
                .catch(function(err) { reject(err); });
        },

        onAuthorize: function(data) {

            // Note: you can display a confirmation page before executing

            var EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/payment_execute/';

            paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL,
                    { paymentID: data.paymentID, payerID: data.payerID })

                .then(function(data) { window.location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/payment_done/")  })
                .catch(function(err) { window.location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkout/payment_error/") });
        }

    }, '#paypal-button');
</script>
```

From logs looks like I am successfully creating payment object, but failing to redirect, in dev tools i am seeing this:

VM6073:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse ()
    at XMLHttpRequest. (https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js:10511:38)

After researching online seems like json is expected but i am returning html? Can anyone point me in the right direction.

I am new to programming so any help is appreciated!